# Using Angular's matAutocomplete, how do I display an object's property, but reference the object itself elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, angular, mat-autocomplete

For example I have the markup:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project #" name="project" [(ngModel)]="key" (ngModelChange)="filterProjects(key);"  matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="setProject($event.option.value)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let project of filtered" [value]="project.ProjNum">
    {{project.ProjNum}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>

<div class="input-group-append">
  <button class="btn btn-info" (click)="load(selectedProject)">Load</button>
</div>
```

When an option is selected, it calls the `setProject()` function, which sets the selectedProject used later for my Load button.  However, as it currently functions, binding the value to `[value]="project.ProjNum"` will call setProject with the project number.  While it would seem intuitive to set my value to `[value]="project"` (and this will set my `selectedProject` to the project object), it will now show `[object Object]` in my input field.

How do I modify this so I can directly reference the `project` object outside of my options, and not just the selected and displayed property?

**Note:** I know I could just use the ProjNum to filter through my list of projects to find the correct one and then set my `selectedProject`, but I would rather not waste resources cycling through a list when I already have the object I want.

Comment: It would be really nice if angular2+ supported binding values using as.  For example, I could bind `[value]="project as project.ProjNum"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `displayWith` function. It allows you to define a function that returns the value in which you want to be displayed

From the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples):

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Assignee" aria-label="Assignee" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>



import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface User {
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title Display value autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-display-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-display-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-display-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteDisplayExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    {name: 'Mary'},
    {name: 'Shelley'},
    {name: 'Igor'}
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: It really must be a Friday, I was looking at the matAutocomplete docs for about 30 min and still didn't see this.  Thank you!